# How can I crop an image with negative crop-boundaries in Java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, crop

I have an image of some arbitrary size, and I need to crop it with negative boundary values.

So, basically I have image (1) and I want to crop it to the dimensions of (2).

```
         (1)
          +---------------------------+
 (2)      |                           |
  +-----------------------------+     |
  |       |                     |     |
  |       |                     |     |
  |       |                     |     |
  |       |                     |     |
  +-----------------------------+     |
          |                           |
          +---------------------------+
```

Any ideas on how to solve this in Java?

I've tried the [Scalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) library, but it doesn't support negative crop boundaries.

Comment: Do you want the resulting image to have the size of (2) or the size of the intersection of (1) and (2)?

Comment: @Baz The latter. I want the resulting image to have the size of the intersection of (1) and (2). Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Well, then you can easily transform the coordinates/bounds of (2) to be non-negative and crop it afterwards. Or just accept the answer of Dan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a library for this task.

You can create the new image that is resulted this way:

```
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, imageType);
```

Then you can crop the piece you need from the old image this way:

```
BufferedImage tempImage = oldImage.getSubimage(0, y, otherWidth, height);
```

Then, you place the `tempImage` in the `newImage`:

```
Graphics2D g2 = newImage.createGraphics();
g2.drawImage(tempImage, x, 0, otherWidth, height, null);
g2.dispose();
```

- `width` is the image1 width
- `height` is the image1 width
- `x` is the top intersection point between the 2 images on the x axis
- `y` is the top intersection point between the 2 images on the y axis
- `otherWidth` is `width - x`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I've put the steps into a minor other order and pasted a complete example here http://pastie.org/4790687 as your variable names  (e.g. otherWidth) didn't make it clear what values you were referring to.

Answer (score -1):

Cant you just put the image inside a div set to display as block with a set height and width then just position the image to the right of the containing div?

Comment: No I can't, or rather that won't solve my problem. I was specifically asking for ways to edit an image itself. Not for ways to display an image on a website.