# javascript/jQuery plugin for cropping images with negative crop boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have a problem similar to this one, but in different technology:
[How can I crop an image with negative crop-boundaries in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458907/how-can-i-crop-an-image-with-negative-crop-boundaries-in-java)

I need a plugin which is able to crop an image with area partially outside the original image. True cropping will be performed in the backend (crop coordinates will be sent there), but some UI/Plugin is required to choose image and select area.

So, basically I have image (1) and I want to crop it to the dimensions of (2).

```
         (1)
          +---------------------------+
 (2)      |                           |
  +-----------------------------+     |
  |       |                     |     |
  |       |                     |     |
  |       |                     |     |
  |       |                     |     |
  +-----------------------------+     |
          |                           |
          +---------------------------+
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this in Javasript/jQuery/HTML5?

I've tried few plugins, but they don't support negative crop boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

**The Html5 Canvas element works fine with clipping regions having negative coordinates.**

[image]

Example code and a Demo:

```js
        var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var ctx1=canvas1.getContext("2d");
        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var cw=canvas.width;
        var ch=canvas.height;

var x=-30;
var y=30;
var w=150;
var h=100;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/reef.jpg";
function start(){

canvas1.width=canvas.width=img.width;
canvas1.height=canvas.height=img.height;

    ctx1.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx1.lineWidth=2;
    ctx1.drawImage(img,0,0);
    drawRect(ctx1,x,y,w,h);
    ctx1.stroke();
  
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    drawRect(ctx,x,y,w,h);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

}

function drawRect(context,x,y,w,h){
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x,y);
    context.lineTo(x+w,y);
    context.lineTo(x+w,y+h);
    context.lineTo(x,y+h);
    context.lineTo(x,y);
    context.closePath();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Unclipped</h4>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
<h4>Clipped with negative rectangle</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```